# Between these two loop, which code is more efficent?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, space-complexity

Code A:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arrayB[i] = 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arrayB[i] *= arrayA[j];
        }

        arrayB[i] /= arrayA[i];
}
```

Code B:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (i < n) {
    if (j == 0)
        arrayB[i] = 1;

    if (j < n) {
        arrayB[i] *= arrayA[j];
        j++;
        continue;
    }

    arrayB[i] /= arrayA[i];
    j = 0;
    i++;
}
```

I know nested loops have a time complexity of O(n^2) and regular loops have O(n), but if I am not wrong, aren't both loop will be iterating the same amount of times? If yes, how come the while() loop can be more efficient than the nested for() loop?

If both have the same time complexity, which loop structure is better to use?

Comment: I believe your question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Neither is "better" to use, honestly, if you consider this could be done O(n) in the first place, and much cleaner than either of the above. Why you wouldn't do that rather than either of these the real question.

Comment: You could compile them w/ enabled optimization and compare assemblers faster than you get answer.

Comment: The while loop above is not more efficient than the nested for loops above (both look the same to me). You seem to imply that while loops are always O(n), but that's not true. Nor are nested for loops always O(n^2), it all depends on the details of what the loops actually do.

Comment: If they have the same time complexity, I'd go with the one that it's clearer and easier to understand. In this case, almost certainly the for loop. As for time complexity, you noted pretty well that both of them are O(n2), however if you are dealing with nonlinear complexity, the while loop could be slower by a "considerable" constant term. Finally, it's important to note that this is an abstract argument, a real compiler might generate almost identical machine code.

Comment: How about "Code C:" -- `for (int i=0; i <n; ++i) arrayB[i] = std::accumulate(arrayA, arrayA + n, 1, std::multiplies<int>()) / arrayA[i];`?  There is no initialization of the `arrayB` items with `1`, and only one hand-written loop (the outer `for` loop).

Comment: How about code D where you explicitly vectorize this, code E where you do that but in multiple threads, code F where you ship the work onto a GPU, code G where you offload the work into a supercluster in the cloud.

Comment: If you count how many times you do `arrayB[i] *= arrayA[j];`, you will find that it is `n^2` in both cases. You have just deconstructed the inner loop into several (pretty incomprehensible) parts.

Comment: OT to your question, but note that if I am not wrong, you can rewrite the whole code to something like `prod = 1; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) prod *= arrayA[i]; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) arrayB[i] = prod / arrayA[i];` Now, you have real _O(n)_ runtime complexity.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why to calculate `std::accumulate(arrayA, arrayA + n, 1, std::multiplies<int>())` in each iteration? It can be calculated only once.

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, it should only be done once.

Answer (score 3):

The second is also a nested loop, you have just obfuscated it by spreading it out.

If you write the `for` version in the equivalent `while` form,

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n)
{
    arrayB[i] = 1;
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < n)
        {
            arrayB[i] *= arrayA[j];
            j++;
        }
        arrayB[i] /= arrayA[i];
    }
    i++;
}
```

and rearrange the `while` version to a slightly more readable equivalent using `else` instead of `continue`,

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (i < n) {
    if (j == 0)
        arrayB[i] = 1;
    if (j < n) { /* Executes once for each 0 <= j < n */
        arrayB[i] *= arrayA[j];
        j++;
    }
    else /* j == n; end of 'j loop' */
    {
        arrayB[i] /= arrayA[i];
        j = 0; /* Restart the 'j loop'. */
        i++;
    }
}
```

it becomes fairly obvious that they do exactly the same amount of work, in almost exactly the same way. The only difference is that your `while` variant is pretty incomprehensible.

The best version is (of course) the one that doesn't try to hide the "for-looping" nature of things behind a bunch of difficult-to-entangle jumping around.

That said, the actually best version runs in linear time - you're computing the same product of `arrayA` for every element of `arrayB`.

This becomes more obvious if you don't reuse `arrayB[i]` for both intermediate results and the final result:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        product *= arrayA[j];
    }
    arrayB[i] = product / arrayA[i];
}
```

Now it's clear that the product computed by the inner loop is the same for all `i` and can be hoisted out of the outer loop.

Summary of today's lesson:

1. Straightforward code that says what you mean can rarely be improved by attempting to be clever
2. Reusing a variable for multiple purposes can hide valuable improvement opportunities

Comment: It might be also interesting that GCC was able to vectorize the `for`-based solution, but not the `while`-based in the second case (the code below). Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8nTG5dGac. Possibly all that branching was too much for the optimizer.

Comment: If interesting, the algorithm can be O(n). You use each element of `arrayB` to find product of A elements, it can be made using one variable. Just take out the 'j' loop. But need to keep in mind any item may be 0 what can change the solution.

Comment: This just goes to show that trying to beat the compiler at the optimization game by writing tricky code can many times render the code *slower* than it should be -- all due to the compiler's optimizer just giving up trying to make sense of the code.  The same thing happens when programmers try to use too many pointers, all in the attempt of speeding up their code.